# Gradient following the shape of the face?

Tags: shaders

I want the gradient to follow the shape of the face. All i am able to achieve by plugging in the gradient node is a circular gradient.
[image]

Comment: Hi @NewBlenderer! Nothing personal :) but this _is_ a very close duplicate, and has already been covered.

Comment: The above solution does not work.

Comment: Hi, @NewBlenderer _None_  of the duplicate suggestions work? If so, can you try the one most suitable to you, let it fail, and edit your question  to illustrate the failure? Maybe share your attempt on  https://blend-exchange.com/ , too. We can reopen the Q, and have a go at fixing that for you.

Comment: @NewBlenderer There are 3 answers. Did you try all three? And if so, what is your not working result opposed to what it should be according to the given answers?